# Overflow and Mismatch Error

Tags: vba, date, row, cell

I have a For loop that runs until there is a blank cell. Column A is the data that is a custom format. I am trying to run a weekly (mon - Fri) report.

42738 returns 1/3/2017

42739 returns 1/4/2017

42740 returns 1/5/2017

and so on

I am trying to figure out how to set a range value to create this weekly report.

The theory I was testing was A3 - A2 = 1 which is mon to tues etc.,

if A3 - A2 = 2 then that shows a weekend.

this is the code I have thus far

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim LastDate As Long
Dim myDate As Integer

Set wks = Worksheets("Labor")
LastDate = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For dRow = 2 To LastDate

    xDate = CInt(Cells(dRow, "A").Value)
    yDate = CInt(Cells(dRow - 1, "A").Value)

    If xDate - yDate = 2 Then
        'weekend
        MsgBox ("Weekend!")

    ElseIf xDate - yDate = 1 Then
        'next day        
    ElseIf xDate - yDate = 0 Then
        'same day       
    Else
        MsgBox (xDate - yDate)

    End If


    myDate = 1

Next dRow
```

My questions are:

How do I fix the overflow error for xDate=?

Why is yDate= a mismatch error?

Is there a cleaner way to write this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dim myDate As long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the date values in your Column A are in their Numeric format (like you mentioned in your post, 42738, 42739, etc.), then the code below will get you what you want.

You don't need to store the date values in the cells in variables, you can directly calculate the difference between each 2 cells using the `DateDiff` function. To read more about the `DateDiff` read [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251417.aspx)

Afterwards, you can use `Select Case` for each type of scenario you want to check.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub NumofWeekdays()

Dim wks             As Worksheet
Dim LastDate        As Long
Dim NumofDays       As Long
Dim dRow            As Long

Set wks = Worksheets("Labor")    
With wks
    LastDate = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For dRow = 2 To LastDate
        NumofDays = DateDiff("d", .Range("A" & dRow - 1).Value, .Range("A" & dRow).Value)                          
        Select Case NumofDays
            Case Is >= 2
                'weekend
                MsgBox "Weekend!"

            Case 1
                'next day
                MsgBox "Next Day"

            Case 0
                'same day
                MsgBox "Same Day"

            Case Else
                MsgBox NumofDays

        End Select
    Next dRow
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I was able to use the DateDiff function! it helped drastically thank you!